# Have Majorana quasiparticles been experimentally realized?

Tags: majorana-fermions

There are many papers claiming that Majorana quasiparticles have been found in different systems. Others papers are more skeptic, e.g. the 2017 discovery was put into question, see for example https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2020/01/200103141035.htm

Have there been any new more conclusive experiments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, no detection has been unambiguous enough to warrant a wide acceptance of the scientific community. The question is still being worked on, see e.g. [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.06893) which was put on the arXiv last week, which states in the abstract that

> Majorana fermions are promising building blocks of forthcoming technology in quantum computing. Their proper identification has remained however a difficult issue, because of concomitant competition with other topologically trivial fermionic states, which can poison the Majorana fermion detection in most spectroscopic probes.